# While running application: Getting error "Index 0 requested, with a size of 0"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting “Index 0 requested, with a size of 0” while starting application on mobile/device.
I am making sure that cursor is not ‘Null’ when I am calling. 
I found some similar issue and tired in my scenario but don’t work.

I have this code:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor resultSet=db.rawQuery("select * from NoteTable", null);
        String[] values = new String[resultSet.getCount()];
        if (resultSet != null && resultSet.moveToNext());
        {
            do {
                if (resultSet != null) {
                    values[i] = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("noteTitle"));
                    i++;
                }
            }while (resultSet.moveToNext());
            resultSet.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return values;
```

I am getting following exception: 
09-24 15:28:23.845  25800-25800/com.example.ashv.actionbar W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ashv.actionbar/com.example.ashv.actionbar.MyActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: You should first move to first record of Cursor by using `resultSet.moveToFirst()`

Comment: you should use `resultSet.moveToFirst()` before traversing the resultset

Comment: Hi Sagar Pilkhwal, I added resultSet.moveToFirst() before IF condition but it doesn't work. I am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should first move to first record of `Cursor` by using `moveToFirst()`, like

```
  if (resultSet != null && resultSet.moveToFirst());
    {
        do {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                values[i] = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("noteTitle"));
                i++;
            }
        }while (resultSet.moveToNext());
        resultSet.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, M D thank you for quick response. I didn't see the difference in code what you have mentioned above and mine. However, as you suggested, I tried as follows, before IF condition but it doesn't work. I am getting same error. resultSet.moveToNext();
if (resultSet != null && resultSet.moveToNext());

Comment: :) got it. My Bad. let me try this.

Comment: I used following, but still same error. Please suggest. if (resultSet != null && resultSet.moveToFirst());

Comment: I tried several things and edit code many times so mistakenly. I have used moveToNext() rather moveToFirst(). However, this is still not working. Appreciate your help. I am getting error while starting my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in code that I have mentioned above in question (of course after Manish correction).

I figured out that in my application, I am using 'App drawer'. 'App drawer' code is checking all contents to display in list and all those supposed to come from data base (i.e. using this code. Reading from database). This is giving me error "Index 0 requested, with a size of 0". This is referring for App drwaer values. I have removed app drawer part and this code works fine (i.e. my application didn't crash and no exception). I need to find solution for dynamic 'App drawer' (this will be different story).

I just mentioned this becasue if you are wondering whats wrong with your code. Then probably you need to look into other sections/module of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should call moveToNext method on the resultSet first

```
while(resultSet.moveToNext){

 if(resultSet != null) {
                values[i] = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("noteTitle"));
            }

}
resultSet.close()
```

for details on reading from sqlite database https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite